# How to initialize a cell array with increasing numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

How could I initialize a cell array with increasing numbers? For a simple array I can do as follow :

```
A = [1:0.0001:1.1]
```

What would be the equivalent for a cell array? How could I obtain:

```
A = {'1', '1.0001', '1.0002', '1.0003', '1.0004', ...}
```

**Edit:**

Here what I have tried so far:

```
cellfun(@(x) num2str(str2double(x)+0.0001), repmat({'1'},1,21), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

However, this gives:

```
{'1.0001', '1.0001', '1.0001',...}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a cool *undocumented* function called `sprintfc` that prints to cell arrays:

```
An = 1:0.0001:1.1;
As = sprintfc('%g',An)
```

Example:

```
>> A = sprintfc('%g',0:0.2:1)
A = 
    '0'    '0.2'    '0.4'    '0.6'    '0.8'    '1'
>> which sprintfc
built-in (undocumented)
```

`sprintfc` was recently highlighted on [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function/). Yet another great find by Yair Altman. Some other possibilities follow.

---

For numerical values, use `num2cell`:

```
A = num2cell(An)
```

For string representations:

```
A = strsplit(num2str(An))
```

You could also use `cellfun`:

```
A = cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(An),'uni',0)
```

Or just `arrayfun`, which is actually simpler:

```
A = arrayfun(@num2str,An,'uni',false)
```

Comment: I don't seem to have the function `strsplit` in R2010a

Comment: @m_power I just remembered there is an undocumented function called `sprintfc` that is perfect for the job.